# User Registration Fails In Keycloak

Tags: python-3.x, django, docker, keycloak, openid-connect

I am performing User Registration process in Django with Keycloak for which I deployed Keycloak docker container (JBoss/Keycloak Version: 16.1.1) and Python version 3.8 and Django Version 4.2.5 .When I was performing the registration process I came across the error as shown in the image below , it shows "**Error registering user**", for more reference image attached below,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSBd6.png)

I couldn't able to register user in Keycloak through Django as the access token generated is not send with user data for registering, couldn't figure out the possible reason for it, also adding the piece of code for better understanding which I have implemented

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':  
        username = request.POST.get('username') 
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        firstname = request.POST.get('firstName')
        lastname = request.POST.get('lastName')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        
        client_id = KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID
        client_secret = KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET
        
        # Request access token from Keycloak
        
        data = {
            'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
            'client_id': client_id,
            'client_secret': client_secret,
        }

        token_url = f'{KEYCLOAK_TOKEN_URL}' 
        r = requests.post(token_url, data=data)
        logger.info('success')

        if r.status_code == 200: 
            access_token = r.json()['access_token']

            headers = {
                'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
            user_url = f'{KEYCLOAK_USER_URL}'  #Posting The User Data To Keycloak
            user_data = {
                'username': username,
                'email': email,
                'firstName': firstname,
                'lastName': lastname,
                'enabled': True,
                'credentials': [{
                    'type': 'password',
                    'value': password
                }]
            }
            user_response = requests.post(user_url, headers=headers, json=user_data)  #If Registration Successful Or Failed 
            if user_response.status_code == 201:
                messages.success(request, 'User registered successfully!')
                return redirect('login')
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Error registering user')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Error obtaining access token')
    return render(request, 'registration.html')
```

I cross checked with Keycloak Openid Configuration URL's and performing REST Operations referred Keycloak Admin Rest API Documentation , also checked is there any version issues.

If possible can someone help me out with this issue or any references regarding it.

Thanks